# jqgrid display on chrome vs firefox

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I am not sure if this is bug on chrome but my last td on the grid is not displaying properly.
Below is screen shot if using FIREFOX

[image: Firefox Display]

While displaying on CHROME is just like this. The width settings is 80px. Temporarily I align it left to at least show the content.

```
{name:'act', index:'act', width:80, align:"left"}
```

[image]

Any experienced with this? my chrome version is 19.0.1084.56 m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of jqGrid are you using?  The team recently released [version 4.4.0](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=974) which corrects some of the display bugs that were showing up in Chrome viz a viz Internet Explorer/Firefox.  I upgraded and many of these display anomalies went away.

Comment: +1 - It would be helpful to have more information, but there were display issues with Chrome and versions of jqGrid earlier than 4.3

Comment: my version is jqgrid is 4.3, I will upgrade and see the results.